# Set notation with points and normal vectors

Tags: vectors

I have a question about mathmatical notation/correctness. I am writing a report about software. This software contains a class that contains a 3D-model with points in a point cloud. After this I used a function that estimates normal unit vectors of these points. Now I am wondering how to put this correctly in my report.

Should I create two sets:

1. A set with just the points $P_i$ in the point cloud. Let's call this set S. So $S = \left \lbrace P_i \right \rbrace$.
2. A set with the normal vectors (containing the points $P_i$ in $S$ as position vectors) and the normal vectors $\mathbf{n_i}$ as direction vectors. Let's call this set $T$. So: $T = \left \lbrace S + \alpha \cdot n_i \right \rbrace$.

Is this the way to go, or is it possible to say that the points $p_i$ in the set $S$ **contain** the normal vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit I am not entirely sure what your normal vectors are. Does your function create some normal unit vector $n_{i}$ with respect to the position vector $P_{i}$? And then $T$ is the set containing these normal vectors and the position vectors? In that case personally I would either create a set 
$$N:=\{n_{i}:n_{i}\cdot P_{i}=0,\|n_{i}\|=1\}$$
 containing the normal unit vectors and say $T=S\cup N$, which is the set containing both the position vectors and the normal unit vectors. Or if you want to avoid as much mathematical notation as possible you could use
$$T=\{n_{i},P_{i}:i=1,...,m\}$$
where $P_{i}$ are the position vectors and $n_{i}$ is a normal unit vector with respect to $P_{i}$.

In general the notation $A+B$ means 
$$A+B=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$$
so this is probably not what you want. I would interpret your notation of $T$ as the set of all sets 
$$S+\alpha n_{i}=\{s+\alpha n_{i}:s\in S\}.$$

I hope this helps, if you give a bit more clarity on what exactly $T$ is I'd be happy to update my answer.

Comment: You got it exactly right. Thank you very much, this is a great help!